# Include Modernizr in RequireJS and have the Modernizr in the head tags

Tags: javascript, requirejs, modernizr

I have a problem with RequireJS and Modernizr.

I want the Modernizr resource to be on the head. And everything else in the body. The reason is that Modernizr need to do some stuffs before DOMContentLoad. I want to be able to load the Modernizr module into other modules using RequireJS. How can I accomplish that both in dev and production environment? I use requirejs that pulls all dependencies and minifies all the resources. And the yeoman build replaces `<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/vendor/require.js"></script>`with the minified version.

**under the body tag:**

```
<!-- build:js ikl.app.js -->
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/vendor/require.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script>
    requirejs.config({

        paths: {

            'jquery'        : 'vendor/jquery',
            'handlebars'    : 'vendor/handlebars',
            'ember'         : 'vendor/ember',
            'ember-data'    : 'vendor/ember-data',
            'modernizr'     : 'vendor/modernizr' // This should be removed


        },

        baseUrl: 'scripts',


        shim: {


            'jquery' : {

                exports : 'jQuery'

            },

            'ember': {

                deps: ['jquery', 'handlebars'],
                exports: 'Ember'

            },

            'ember-data': {

                deps: ['ember'],
                exports: 'DS'

            },

            'handlebars': {

                exports: 'Handlebars'

            },

            'modernizr': {
                exports: 'Modernizr'
            }

        }

    });

    require([

        'modules/system/controllers/system.controller',
        'jquery',
        'ember',
        'ember-data',
        'handlebars',
        'modernizr'

    ], 
        function( systemController ) {
            systemController.renderView();
        }

    );

    </script>
```

Comment: Why not just load Modernizr synchronously in a script element in the head? You'd likely want the page to wait for Modernizr to run so that all CSS classes etc are present and you don't get unsightly 'style jumps' as various css classes suddenly kick in.

Comment: There is a performance gain of having it on the body-tag. It renders the HTML faster and than applies the JS logic. I wan't as little as possible JS logics on the head

Comment: flash-of-unstyled-content is a convicing argument not to render the HTML before Modernizr itself is loaded. Think again.

Answer (score 32):

You should be able to get both.

- First, remove your paths configuration that relates to modernizr, you won't need it
- Next Load Modernizr in the head - this will create a window.Modernizr variable.
- Finally, before your bootstrapping require, define the modernizr module

  ```
  define('modernizr', [], Modernizr);
  require(['foo', 'bar', 'modernizr'], function(foo, bar, modernizr) {
       //..profit
  }
  ```

Comment: I should also state that if you're then optimizing your scripts make sure to exclude 'modernizr' as it does not need to be packaged in the optimized bundles.

Comment: The require optimizer starts at a file and walks the dependency tree bundling together everything into a single optimized (and optionally minified) file. This is a recommended build step before pushing to deployment to minimize request amount and size. When the optimizer sees `'modernizr'` it has no way of knowing this is provided externally by the page, it assumes its in a file like all others and errors  when this can't be found (this is correct and what you want). The solution is to use the `'exclude'` property in your optimizer configuration to tell it not to worry about `'modernizr'`.

Comment: I forgot to mention. This trick will only work when the `typeof` the dependency you're manually providing is `'object'`